# My player doesn't move in my gvr application

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I need to move gvr cam in the game, but in the android app it doesn't move...
I have already tried using this code:

```
public class controller : MonoBehaviour {


private bool walking = false;
private Vector3 spawnPoint;

void Start () {

    spawnPoint = transform.position;
}


void Update () {

    if (walking)
    {
        transform.position = transform.position + Camera.main.transform.forward * 3 * Time.deltaTime;
     }

    if (transform.position.y <-10f)
    {
        transform.position = spawnPoint;
    }

    Ray ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(.5f, .5f, 0));
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit))
    {
        if (hit.collider.name.Contains("plane"))
        {
            walking = false;
        } else
        {
            walking = true;
        }
    }

}
```

[In the image linked here there is my plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMYtd.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's may be this:

```
if (hit.collider.name.Contains("plane"))
```

but on scene You have "Plane" not "plane" ;)

Try to use layers and layerMask instead of checking via name. You can read about this here: [Unity Manual: Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html)